# Can i use <script src="node_modules/...?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I am trying to import Quill ImageUpload Module with they documentation.
Example is:

```
<script src="/node_modules/quill-image-upload/image-upload.min.js"></script>
```

my way is little bit different but still correct

```
<script src="../../node_modules/quill-image-upload/image-upload.min.js"></script>
```

Problem is that when i click in link in source code it gaves me error

```
Cannot GET /node_modules/quill-image-upload/image-upload.min.js
```

What can i do with that?

Comment: Okay, so have you any experience with a technologies such as webpack? If not, then I can give you a link to some good tutorial(s) if you like? That will help you solve your specific problem. Alternatively, you could include the file via CDN or something?

Comment: I only heard about webpack but never actually used it. Dont know how much time it take to implement. But i will be very thankfull for link. They dont have cdn but i can import it like file from sources of course. Just was curious if is this possible too.

Comment: Sure thing, [this free course](https://laracasts.com/series/webpack-for-everyone) will teach you enough to do whatever you like... It covers everything from setting everything up through to using it to turn your SASS into CSS and so on, generally a webpack config file shouldn't take you too long, it might for the first time ever, but that's fine, it's new to you! :)